# Add empty records on sharePoint

Tags: list-template

Having an option to add records to the list based on a page would also be useful for me. Basically this is needed to insert empty records for attendance for all employees at the beginning of the day. The only field that is obligatory in Attendance list is the person name.

Is this possible to create the empty records using an insert query in the database for every day?

Answer (score 1):

when parties other than the Microsoft SharePoint Development Team or Microsoft SharePoint Support agents make changes to the database schema, modify its data, or execute ad hoc queries against the SharePoint databases, put you **unsupported mode.**. That's mean you will not get the supprot from MSFT unless you restore the DB to un modified state. [Support for changes to the databases that are used by Office server products and by Windows SharePoint Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841057?wa=wsignin1.0)

Now for the empty record, You need to develop some piece of TimerJob or May be a Workflow or event receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Timer Job for doing this activity.

Schedule the Job to run every day morning (say 5 AM) and let the Job create the blank record.

Comment: Hi Setting Timer Job would need to edit the code isn't it? Can anything be done on the database to insert empty records?

Comment: Manipulating SharePoint databases directly is not recommended and cause you to loose warranty. If you want to go ahead with that approach, the i would suggest running SQL profiler and check what all database tables are getting affected during an insert from Web UI.

Comment: Can we use windows task scheduler to do this?

Comment: Yes. You can create PowerShell script and then use Task Scheduler to run it every day. The problem with this approach is maintenance. Also need to manually migrate this job in case of server changes etc.

Comment: Hi, how about workflows? can we set a workflow to create the empty records?